# MultiViewPager with multiple view

Tags: android

I have a problem,I can't figure out how do i add images to my MultiViewPager.

i have seen a lot of examples but i don't understand what should i do after i create the MultiViewPager layout.

```
<com.pixplicity.multiviewpager.MultiViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:matchChildWidth="@+id/iv_gallery" />
```

this is my image xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/iv_gallery"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my java code :

```
pager = (MultiViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        pager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return images.length;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                return view == (ImageView) object;
            }

            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_gallery);

                imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

                return imageView;

            }
        });
```

what is wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your function `instantiateItem()` you need to add the view you created to the `container` param passed in.

like that

```
container.addView(imageView);
```

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
it's actually weird because i have used findViewById to find it.

Comment: No dude, you need to create a new image view for each instantiateItem() call, you can't find one from the activity like you're doing now
Instead make imageView = new ImageView(Context);

Comment: this causes another exception:  java.lang.NullPointerException: MatchWithChildResId did not find that ID in the first fragment of the ViewPager; is that view defined in the child view's layout? Note that MultiViewPager only measures the child for index 0.

Comment: According to code here https://gist.github.com/pflammertsma/754d55a11e4329baee77
you need to setMatchChildWidth with an id of the view